# vacuum expectation value and Casimir effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Is it correct to say that the VEV of the SM Higgs is 246 GeV?  If so, is the VEV a reflection, or measure, of the Casimir Effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that the VEV of the SM Higgs is 246 GeV?

Depending slightly on your conventions then yes, this is correct. If you use the other convention it is $v/\sqrt{2}\approx 174\ \mathrm{GeV}$. Note that the vev is the *value* of the Higgs field in the vacuum, not the *energy*! The Higgs field itself has units of energy, but its value is not the same as its energy. To connect the two you need to know the [Higgs potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMecanismo_de_Higgs_PH.png).

> If so, is the VEV a reflection, or measure, of the Casimir Effect?

It really has nothing to do with the [Casimir effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) which is a force between objects due to excluding modes of a field between them (Note that it doesn't have to be a *quantum* field, and there doesn't have to be any vacuum energy! See the video of the Casimir effect in a water tank on the wiki page! There are many common misstatements of the Casimir effect.).

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  Your answers are very clear, I appreciate that!